# Product display: no scroll of product list

Tags: commerce

I have an issue with commerce product display setup page - scroll function for product list disappeared (part where one can choose a product assigned to display) so I am not able to choose products on lower positions. Only first 10 products can be chosen. Any ideas how to reestablish a full product list?

Comment: Which product display exactly,what is the link? Are you using views? If you are using views then check for pager settings.

Comment: when you add a product display in commerce there is a section to choose which product is linked with this display. Will check views setting. thanks